# TensorFlow: failure to convert elements of BinaryCrossentropy to Tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow

I´m following an online course for TensorFlow, but one of the examples that works in the video does not work for me (I've checked - there are no typos).

I have a feature array `X` of shape `(1000,2)` and a label array `y` of shape `(1000,)`.
Here's the code that fails for me:

```
# 1. Create the model using the Sequential API
model_1 = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)
])

# 2. Compile it
model_1.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy,
                optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(),
                metrics=['accuracy'])

# 3. Fit it
model_1.fit(X, y, epochs=5)
```

The error occurs in the `fit()` method:

```
 TypeError: Failed to convert elements of <keras.src.losses.BinaryCrossentropy object at 0x79aa68216da0> to Tensor. Consider casting elements to a supported type. See https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/dtypes for supported TF dtypes.
```

I have tried to manually convert the numpy arrays to tensors with type `tf.float64`, but the error remains.

I think it could be a version problem: in the video the TensorFlow version is 2.3.0, whereas mine is 2.13.0.

So my question is, which elements would have to be cast to which types to make this code work?

Comment: In your loss, typo `()`, i.e. `tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy()`. but if you use method, then you do  `tf...binary_crossentroy`

Comment: Thank you - this fixed my problem. I guess i was confused because so far i had only used ``mae`` which is passed without ``()``

Comment: No worries. Happy learning :). FYI, in keras, method's name usually lowercase, and uppercase if that is a class. `mae` is method, and `keras.losses.MeanAbsoluteError()` is class, ref https://keras.io/api/losses/